# counterexample to strauss inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a counterexample to Strauss inequality in dimension 1, where it supposedly fails. How can one construct an $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ function which does not decay at infinity, for which for instance
$$|u(x)|>C|x|^{-\alpha}||u||_{H^1}?$$
for some $\alpha>0$?

Comment: In any dimension $n \geq 2$, the inequality states that $$|U(x)| \leq C |x|^{(1-n)/2}\|U\|_{H^1}$$ for $|x| \geq 1$, where $U$ is a radial function. Hence $U$ must decay also for $n=2$.